# How does etrade use touchid without the passcode fallback?

Tags: ios, touch-id

LocalAuthentication will let you fallback to require manual password entry but if you use the keychain touchid workflow the fallback is passcode.

Either they're not storing it in the keychain and using their own encrypted local persistence unlocked only by successful or there is a nuance I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said if they are using Keychain to store the password and retrieve if by TouchID, the passcode option is mandatory and cannot be modified by the developer.

My guess is that they simply use LocalAuthentication to request a True or False for TouchID authentication and has nothing to do with keychain. Thus Passcode option will be no longer mandatory.